# concerning QLineEdit, can I change completers at runtime?

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete

For this project, I am using a custommade completer as to complete text not only at the beginning of the stringlist, but also from anywhere in the strings of the stringlist. For example: if the stringlist contains "*Ann, Arial, Bass, Fra, John*", then typing the letter 'A' would default give only "**A***nn*" and "**A***rial*". With this customized completer, typing the letter 'A' will also give "*B***a***ss*" and "*Fr***a**".

This complete code can be found at [mycompleter.cpp](http://qt-mequine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mycompleter.cpp) and [mycompleter.h](http://qt-mequine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mycompleter.h) .

This has been working fine during the project. I load the wordlist from a database at startup and work from there.

Now, my problem is the following: as the project now needs a new functionality, the database containing the wordlist can be altered at runtime. This means that, after making alterations, I should reload the wordlist for the completer.

Currently, the program starts to crash. Not everytime, but 'sometimes'. I cannot exactly reproduce the crash. I just keep on trying to alter the database (to invoke a 'reload' from the Completer), and thanks to some debugging I found that it crashed 'sometimes' at line 5 `QObject::disconnect(c, 0, this, 0);`.

Can anyone shed a light on this? Did I do something terribly wrong? As I can't reproduce the crash 'every' time, I am quite confused in this one, any help is very welcome.

The code is:

```
void MyLineEdit::setCompleter(MyCompleter *completer)
{
    if (c)
    {
        QObject::disconnect(c, 0, this, 0);
    }

    c = completer;

    if (!c)
    {
        return;
    }

    c->setWidget(this);
    connect(completer, SIGNAL(activated(const QString&)), this, SLOT(insertCompletion(const QString&)));
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of line 5?

Comment: Line 5 disconnects everything between the old `MyCompleter` and `MyLineEdit`

Comment: If it sometimes crashes at startup check that `c` is properly initialized. Also you are likely to have a memory leak, you should `delete` the old completer before assigning a new one, then you can skip the disconnect completely.

Comment: In your constructor of `MyLineEdit` are you setting `c` to a null pointer value? Also, have you set a connection to `destroyed()` signal so you can set `c` to a null pointer value if it gets destroyed somewhere else so your line edit doesn't think its still valid?

Comment: @Nejat : indeed, I am curious to the need of line 5 (this class is not my own code). I have noticed that if I leave it out, and simply assign a new completer to MyLineEdit, it will take the new completer and it will work. I haven't had a crash since. Is this a bad solution? It feels a bit "sketchy".

Comment: @lazycoder : it never crashes at startup. `c` is properly initialized, but indeed I should `delete` it as well to prevent memory leaks (isn't this included in the "disconnect"?)

Comment: @RobbieE : thank you vor your comment, in the constructor `c` is correctly set to a null pointer value. Can you explain how to set this "connection" to destroyed() that you are talking about? Maybe that is the solution? You mean I have to override that function?

Comment: It's fairly simple. All derived classes of `QObject` emit the `destroyed()` signal just before they are destroyed. When you set the completer, connect this signal to a private slot so that, if the completer is destroyed, you set `c` to a null pointer value. If you don't keep track of whether `c` is destroyed or not, it could end up being a dangling pointer, which will give the behaviour you're experiencing.

Comment: No the deletion of an object is not included in the disconnect, but the disconnect is included in the delete. So if you `delete` it you don't have to do the `disconnect`

Comment: @lazycoder Does this mean that, if I change line#5 to `delete c` (instead of QObject::disconnect() ), it should work and no longer crash? If this is so, I will put it as an answer to this question. (Or both you guys can do it as you earned the reward for bearing with me :-) )

Comment: @RobbieE : same remark as to lazycoder:  Does this mean that, if I change line#5 to delete c (instead of QObject::disconnect() ), it should work and no longer crash? If this is so, I will put it as an answer to this question. (Or both you guys can do it as you earned the reward for bearing with me :-) )